# Call a redis command outside of transaction context

Tags: php, redis, predis

Is it possible to call a predis command outside of transaction context? I mean to exec hget or hexist while a transaction is opened

Comment: Sounds like you need to use a Lua script instead of a tx - you can read and write data in the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it`s not possible. [Transaction](http://redis.io/topics/transactions) started with ([MULTI](http://redis.io/commands/MULTI)) works in per connection pipeline. So you should [DISCARD](http://redis.io/commands/discard)/[EXEC](http://redis.io/commands/exec) first or use another predis connection to Redis server.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it, but not on the same connection.

Here's a transaction that copies `foo2` value to `foo`, `foo2` is read by a second connection:

```
$responses = $client1->transaction()->set('foo', $client2->get('foo2'))->get('foo')->execute();
```

Comment: What's new adds your answer?

Comment: @misterion, I'm performing a redis call while a transaction is still open. I think that this is what the OP wanted.